# testing if input var $1 is encased in single quotes or not

Tags: bash

I have a script that requires the user to input some text, like `$ script.sh someText`, but I need to ensure the input the user types is encased in single quotes like `$ script.sh 'someText'`. But I can't seem to figure out how to test for the quotes.

There are other limitations regarding what kind of input the user can enter, such as no spaces and of course no single quotes as part of their input, both of which I easily test for by reading `$1`, but how do I read if single quotes, which are correctly not read by BASH as part of the input var $1, are used to open and close the user's input?

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell whether the command line was written with single quotes, double quotes or no quotes, because the shell removes them all.

If you have a script `echoit`:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Then you can run it as:

```
echoit No\ Quotes "Double Quotes" 'Single Quotes'
```

And the output will be:

```
No Quotes
Double Quotes
Single Quotes
```

Comment: makes sense that the shell strips quotes from user input. The user, though, might well, and is even expected to input special chars as part of input, so single quotes encasing input ensures the script gets input as user intended. If user, for example, inputs `$ script.sh E/$G`, without the single quotes script will read input as `E/` only bc the `$G` part is, TBH, I am not sure what happens to it. But I do know single quotes are required to ensure all chars get passed to script as user inputs. I am thinking maybe `read` or `zenity` to force surrounding input with single quotes.

Comment: Does it help if I tell you: if the user has `G="Giant Mushroom"` set as a shell variable, then `echoit 'E/$G' "E/$G" E/$G` will produce `E/$G`, `E/Giant Mushroom`, `E/Giant` and `Mushroom` as the 4 lines of output.

Comment: @nanker If special characters are expected cant you just check for them in the script ?

Comment: The example text, `E/$G`, which a user might enter probably reads convoluted. My badd. Those are just 4 chars a user could enter with no intention of passing `$G` as a var. Just that combo of chars, when not enclosed in single quotes, is an example of an entry that would not get passed to the script as the user intends. It is the script, really, that demands the single quotes to ensure it reads in as `$1` everything the user typed.

Comment: @jidder the script could test for special chars if it knew in advance what input a user might type. But script only expects some input from user, consisting of a combination of 90 chars (92 minus the single quote and space chars that are not allowed). But if user does't enclose input in single quotes some of what they type might not be passed to script. Continuing with example,if user types `E/$G` as input without enclosed single quotes, then only `E/` is passed to the script, and the script does not know the user actually typed in 4 instead of 2 chars.

Comment: It seems quite likely I guess that there may well be no way, in Bash at least, around this.

Comment: @nanker: I think your conclusion is correct; there is no (trivial) way around this problem in Bash when the user is responsible for typing the command line.  If you have a program generate the command line, you can deal with all sorts of issues, but while the user isn't constrained, the user isn't constrained to do what you want.  Fundamentally, you train them to always surround each argument with single quotes (which isn't too painful if single quotes can never appear in the value).

Comment: Actually I just tried employing a zenity text entry dialogue in which to enter user input and it works fine. Input gets passed to script as type regardless what char combo is. Zenitys adds an extra step but removes quoting headache, so its the win atm.